# What is best practice to store 50000+ records in mysql in a single transaction

Tags: java, mysql, load-data-infile

Input set: thousands(>10000) of csv files, each containing >50000 entries.
output: Store those data in mysql db.

Approach taken:
Read each file and store the data into database. Below is the code snippet for the same. Please suggest if this approach is ok or not.

```
    PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
try 
{
pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
result = pstmt1.executeUpdate();
con.setAutoCommit(false);
sqlQuery = "insert   into "
        + tableName
        + " (x,y,z,a,b,c) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
Path file = Paths.get(filename);

lines = Files.lines(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
final int batchsz = 5000;
for (String line : (Iterable<String>) lines::iterator) {

    pstmt2.setString(1, "somevalue");
    pstmt2.setString(2, "somevalue");
    pstmt2.setString(3, "somevalue");
    pstmt2.setString(4, "somevalue");
    pstmt2.setString(5, "somevalue");
    pstmt2.setString(6, "somevalue");
    pstmt2.addBatch();
    if (++linecnt % batchsz == 0) {
        pstmt2.executeBatch();
    }
}
int batchResult[] = pstmt2.executeBatch();
pstmt2.close();
con.commit();

} catch (BatchUpdateException e) {
    log.error(Utility.dumpExceptionMessage(e));

} catch (IOException ioe) {
    log.error(Utility.dumpExceptionMessage(ioe));
} catch (SQLException e) {
    log.error(Utility.dumpExceptionMessage(e));
} finally {
    lines.close();
    try {
        pstmt1.close();
        pstmt2.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Utility.dumpExceptionMessage(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would try an bulk export to dump or import to insert them all.

Comment: Shall we clarify the terminology? In sql world dump means data that has been exported from a database either as a set of sql queries, csv or a proprietor format. Getting data from a dump or into a database is called importing or loading. Now if you could clarify your question ...

Comment: I recently handled a similar problem, in my case the data is 600,000+. My solution is using multithread and blocking queue to import the data. However, multithreading does not actually improve the performance, it only reduces the response time. If you really want to make it quicker, consider parallel solution. But 50,000 is too small to parallelize, the complexity is far outweigh the benefit. Therefore, I suggest you stick with single thread with bulk insertion.

Comment: @e4c5 - thanks for the clarification. I've modified the title. The goal is, read the csv files, and store the data into db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Ridrigo has already pointed out, LOAD DATA INFILE is the way to go. Java is not really needed at all.

If the format of your CSV is not something that can directly be inserted into the database, your Java code can renter the picture. Use it to reorganize/transform the CSV and save it as another CSV file instead of writing it into the database.

You can also use the Java code to iterate through the folder that contains the CSV, and then execute the system command for the

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("mysql -p password -u user database -e 'LOAD DATA INFILE ....");
```

you will find that this is much much faster than running individual sql queries for each row of the CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

I've used LOAD DATA INFILE ins situations like this in the past.

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a
>   table at a very high speed. LOAD DATA INFILE is the complement of
>   SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE. (See Section 14.2.9.1, “SELECT ... INTO
>   Syntax”.) To write data from a table to a file, use SELECT ... INTO
>   OUTFILE. To read the file back into a table, use LOAD DATA INFILE. The
>   syntax of the FIELDS and LINES clauses is the same for both
>   statements. Both clauses are optional, but FIELDS must precede LINES
>   if both are specified.

The IGNORE number LINES option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use IGNORE 1 LINES to skip over an initial header line containing column names:

> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

Comment: These csv file format is custom. It has initial some lines with some device details and after that, the column names and its respective values continue. Can those initial lines be ignored ?

Comment: Edit with "IGNORE LINES", hope it helps.

Comment: Really helpful with your detailed description.